# What is the complexity of deciding if the number of independent sets in a graph exceeds a given threshold?

Tags: graph-theory

Given an (undirected) graph G, let i(G) be the number of independent sets [1] in G. Given also a threshold th, the problem is to decide whether $i(G) > th$.

Are there known values of th for which the problem is known to be intractable?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)

Comment: Do you mean independent sets here or maximal independent sets?

Comment: The problem "given $G$ and an integer $th$, are there at least $th$ independent sets in $G$" does not admit efficient randomized algorithms unless $\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{RP}$ by a well-known result of Allan Sly [FOCS 2010]. Are you asking for a specific value of $th=th(n)$, which necessarily grows with the number of vertices?